# Is there a way to use engagement splits based off of activity of more than one email?

Tags: workflow, journeybuilder

I'm new to SFMC and to journey builder in general. I'm currently running a journey with multiple emails and I want to base an engagement  step on whether some has clicked email 1 OR 2. Currently, I don't see a way to base engagement off of more than 1 email. Is the only way to do this, to have 2 engagement steps back to back? That way seems a little cumbersome.